# Probability sets with a prime number

Tags: probability

I've been trying to hone my probability skills and i came upon this question that i have no idea where to even start with. I Let $\Omega = \{1,2,\ldots,p\}$ where $p$ is prime, and suppose that all members of $\Omega$ are equally likely. I then have to show that if $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then at least one of $A$ and $B$ is either $\varnothing$ or $\Omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{|A\cap B|}{p} = \overbrace{\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\vphantom{\frac 11}}^{\Large\text{by independnence}} = \frac{|A|}{p} \cdot \frac{|B|} p
$$
Multiply both sides by $p^2:$
$$
|A\cap B| \cdot p = |A||B|
$$
Since $0\le|A|\le p$ and $0\le|B|\le p,$ you cannot have either $|A|$ or $|B|$ divisible by $p$ unless it it equal to either $0$ or $p.$

Comment: Euclid's lemma is relevant here: a prime divides the product of two numbers only if it divides at least one of them.

Comment: Ah i understand now thankyou, just a quick question, where does the second line of;   |AnB| . p^2 = |A||B|p     come from? As i thought it would be |AnB| . p = |A||B|p. ?

Comment: @freddie.l1 : You have $\dfrac{|A\cap B|} p = \dfrac{|A|} p \cdot \dfrac{|B|} p,$ and you multiply both sides by $p^2.$ You get $|A\cap B| \cdot p = |A| |B|. \quad$ (I initially multiply by $p$ one more time than was needed.) $\qquad$